# Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Reading and watching this presentation:
http://boost-spirit.com/home/2011/06/12/ast-construction-with-the-universal-tree/
I've discovered this statement -- basically we are suggested not to use semantic actions.

I must admit, that I've already felt something like that: grammars with semantic actions actually look kinda ugly. and, when I needed to extend/change them, it took a lot of "micromanagement" exactly with semantic actions. The approach with attribute grammar, demonstrated in the presentation, seems to be much more elegant and promising.

So I'd like to ask: is this is an "official" point? Should I learn how to work with attribute grammar and avoid semantic actions in more detail? If so -- I'd like to = ask for some basic (maybe even trivial) examples, demonstrating such an approach -- the LISP interpreter is too complex for me to chew...

Comment: Best asked on the Spirit-General list...

Comment: What "LISP interpreter"? is there a LISP interpreter written in Spirit somewhere?

Comment: Ah, I see, in the linked slides: https://github.com/boostcon/2011_presentations/raw/master/fri/utree_talk.pdf

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<sub>I'm sure Hartmut will answer in a second. Till then, this is my take:</sub>

**No** that is not an official point.

Semantic actions have some drawbacks

- The simplest *disadvantage* of semantic actions is the stylistic notion of **separation of concerns**. You want to express *syntax* in one place, and *semantics* in another. This helps maintainability (especially with regards to the lengthy compile times for compiling Spirit Grammars)
- More complicated implications if they have side-effects (which is frequently the case). Imagine backtracking from a parsed node when the semantic action had a **side-effect**: the parser state will be reverted, but the external effects aren't.

  In a way, using attributes *only* is like using deterministic, pure functions in a functional program, it is easier to reason about the correctness of a program (or, in this case the *grammar* state machine) when it is *composed* of pure functions only.
- Semantic actions have a tendency (but not necessarily so) to introduce more copying around by value; this, in combination with heavy backtracking, could **reduce performance**. Of course, if the semantic action is 'heavy' this, in itself, is going to hinder performance of parsing.

---

Semantic actions are good for various purposes. In fact, if you need to parse non-trivial grammars with context sensitivity you cannot escape them.

1. Consider the use of `qi::locals<>` and *inherited attributes* (code from the [`Mini XML - ASTs!` sample](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html)) - they involve semantic actions:

   ```
   xml =
           start_tag                   [at_c<0>(_val) = _1]
       >>  *node                      
       >>  end_tag(at_c<0>(_val)) // passing the name from the 
                                  // ... start_tag as inherited attribute
   ;
   ```

   Or [one using qi::locals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html):

   ```
   rule<char const*, locals<char> > rl;
   rl = alpha[_a = _1] >> char_(_a); // get two identical characters
   test_parser("aa", rl); // pass
   test_parser("ax", rl); // fail
   ```

   IMO, these semantic action pose less of a problem usually, because when they get backtracked, the next time execution passes (the same) semantic action, the *local* will just get overwritten by the new, correct, value.
2. Also, some jobs are really 'quick-and-dirty' and don't warrant the use of *utree* or a hand-rolled AST type:

   ```
    qi::phrase_parse(first, last, // imagine qi::istream_iterator... 
        intesting_string_pattern  // we want to match certain patterns on the fly
               [ log_interesting_strings ], // and pass them to our logger
        noise_skipper             // but we skip all noise
    );
   ```

   Here, the semantic action is the *core* of the parsers function. It works, because no backtracking is involved at the level of nodes with semantic actions.
3. The semantic actions are a mirror-image of semantic actions in Spirit Karma, where they usually pose less of the problems than in Qi; so even if only for interface/API consistency, semantic actions are 'a good thing' and enhance the usability of Boost Spirit as a whole.

Comment: What can you say about the semantic actions in the latest version of the library (**X3**)? Will they be present there?

Comment: @Dukales Of course they will. Semantic actions could have down-sides, but not having them is much more crippling. I don't have much hands on experience with X3 though